# Compute candlesticks in real time

Tags: python, mongodb, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have a real time Mongo database with tickers for different symbols. Based on this tickers I want to compute candlesticks in real time for 1 minute, 5 minutes etc. How can I make this without overloading the database and to be more efficient?

I am using python as programming language and I can change the database if it will be easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Read https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb for inspiration. The article might be a bit outdated, yet it describes an idea of pre-aggregated data for real-time dashboards quite well. There are more specialised databases for time-series data tho. InfluxDB, OpenTSDB, to name a few.